# How to create an Intellij and Eclipse compatible code style and code formatting configuration (for java code)?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, code-formatting, intellij-idea

Few weeks ago I tried Intellij and I found it really awesome. Now, at my project there are two programmers (including me) using Intellij and few other programmers who are going to keep using Eclipse. Since this project is already very large and it's going to grow a lot, we need to use compatible Code Style and Code Formatting between Intellij and Eclipse. We do not want to have problems when one user edits some file and reformats it before saving. With Eclipse "alone" we used to have some exported configuration, and before anybody starts to work, the first step is just to import this configuration. We already tried to use External Code Formatter, but it didn't work on Intellij 9.

So, I have a bunch of questions here:

1. Is there any way to import eclipse formatting configuration on Intellij 9?
2. Anybody could share their experience managing this kind of situation? Do you guys have any other suggestion to manage this situation?

Answer (score 17):

There is an updated plugin for IDEA, called Eclipse Code Formatter:
http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6546

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend someone spends the time to configure their IntelliJ's code style to be the same as Eclipse. This will take a little time and effort but once it is done, you can export it just like in eclipse so that any other IDEA users can import it.

You could also search online to see if anyone has already done this and you can simply download the code style config and use it.

The only alternative I can think of would be to find a standardized code style template that is available for both eclipse and IntelliJ, like the Recommended Sun Java Code Style.

Comment: I sure would appreciate it but in the years I've been a developer, I've never heard of anyone having a lot of success at this.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be [a plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1605) for that (emerged from [this discussion](http://plugins.intellij.net/wishlist/item/?wid=127)).

Comment: We already tried that, but it doesn't work on Intellij 9. :-(