# How to avoid endless formatting cycle eclipse vs intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm working on a large java project and most if not all developers are using Eclipse. I'm allowed to use intellij idea as long as there is no change in the formatting.

I tried to tweak my intellij formatter settings to make it achieve the same formatting rules as defined by eclipse. We're using a slightly modified version of the sun formatting standards.

However there is one difference in the two formatters that I could not configure away. It arises when you define a method with an argument list that does not fit on one line, either because the argument type names, argument variable names or number of arguments is too large. Example:

```
  // idea
  int foo(int _______________________________________________________________a,
          int _______________________________________________________________b) {
    return 0;
  }
```

Intellij idea will left-align the second row of arguments with the opening parentheses of the parameter declaration. Use C-M-L to apply this formatting rule in intellij idea.

```
  // eclipse
  int foo(int _______________________________________________________________a,
      int _______________________________________________________________b) {
    return 0;
  }
```

Eclipse will indent the second row of arguments by a fixed number of spaces, in this case 4. Use C-S-F to apply this formatting rule in eclipse.

Repeatedly formatting the same file with the two editors produces an endless reformatting cycle which is very unpleasant to watch in version control history. Is there a way to fix this either in the eclipse settings or preferably in the idea settings?

Comment: When I'm on a project that uses Eclipse, I have two IDEs: IDEA for Coding and Eclipse for formatting and checking in. I don't know any other solution for that. sry.

Comment: So, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744113/eclipse-lining-up-function-arguments-vertically)?

Comment: Thanks ordous I was looking for this

Comment: I'd suggest that this gets marked as a duplicate of the question linked in Ordous answer. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604118/438960) is a slightly different question, and did not contain the anwer I was looking for.